# Asp.net project building error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

i am getting below error while building my project
**Error 4   Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Orchard.Framework, Version=1.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.**

Even i have integrated orchard.core dll and orcahrd.framework dll refrence in my project,but nothing to do with orchard anything with my project but don't know why this error is coming and what's the reason behind this.

Please help me due to this i am unable to move forward in my project.

Thanks

Comment: either the reference is corrupt or you are missing something

Comment: If you are not using the reference in you project then Allow the error to execute and trace the error to find out the line of the file where it is existing and remove the piece of line from the project file.(mostly the line will be in web.config or so).

Answer (score 0):

Check that the version of the Ochard.Framework.dll i 1.5.1.0

Latest version is 1.7.2, so it might be that the web.config file specify version 1.5.1.0 while the version you have is 1.7.2.